# the modal closes the previous modal when show

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I created a class for my modal, where show method creates a main modal, and the other creates a confirmation modal, to be called when the user is going to close the modal ('do you really want to close?'), but when I call the confirmation modal the main mode is closed.

I'm using this library:
https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

modal code:

```js
class dialogModal{
  // class responsável pelo modal
  constructor(objModal){
      this.title = objModal.title
      this.message = objModal.message
      this.buttons = objModal.buttons
  }
  show(){
  // função para criar modal
      var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
          title: this.title,
          message: this.message,
          buttons: this.buttons
      });
      dialog.open();
  }
  confirm(){
      var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
          size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_SMALL,
          title: 'do you really want to close?', 
          message: '<p>do you really want to close?</p>',
          buttons: [{ label: 'cancel', cssClass: 'btn btn-danger', action: function(dialogRef){dialogRef.close();}}, 
                    {label: 'close', cssClass: 'btn btn-primary', action: BootstrapDialog.closeAll ()}]
      });
      dialog.open();
  }
}

modal = new dialogModal({message: ''});
modal.title = '<h4>Edit</h4>'
modal.message = '<b>123</b>'
modal.buttons = [{ label: 'cancel', cssClass: 'btn btn-danger', action: modal.confirm},
{ label: 'save', cssClass: 'btn btn-primary',action:alert('ok')}];
modal.show();
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--modal-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js" integrity="sha512-LbO5ZwEjd9FPp4KVKsS6fBk2RRvKcXYcsHatEapmINf8bMe9pONiJbRWTG9CF/WDzUig99yvvpGb64dNQ27Y4g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `function` to `action:`, rather than calling the `function`.

i.e.

you need to change `BootstrapDialog.closeAll()` to `BootstrapDialog.closeAll`

```js
class dialogModal{
  // class responsável pelo modal
  constructor(objModal){
      this.title = objModal.title
      this.message = objModal.message
      this.buttons = objModal.buttons
  }
  show(){
  // função para criar modal
      var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
          title: this.title,
          message: this.message,
          buttons: this.buttons
      });
      dialog.open();
  }
  confirm(){
      var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
          size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_SMALL,
          title: 'do you really want to close?', 
          message: '<p>do you really want to close?</p>',
          buttons: [{ label: 'cancel', cssClass: 'btn btn-danger', action: function(dialogRef){dialogRef.close();}}, 
                    {label: 'close', cssClass: 'btn btn-primary', action: BootstrapDialog.closeAll }]
      });
      dialog.open();
  }
}

modal = new dialogModal({message: ''});
modal.title = '<h4>Edit</h4>'
modal.message = '<b>123</b>'
modal.buttons = [{ label: 'cancel', cssClass: 'btn btn-danger', action: modal.confirm},
{ label: 'save', cssClass: 'btn btn-primary',action:alert('ok')}];
modal.show();
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--modal-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js" integrity="sha512-LbO5ZwEjd9FPp4KVKsS6fBk2RRvKcXYcsHatEapmINf8bMe9pONiJbRWTG9CF/WDzUig99yvvpGb64dNQ27Y4g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand how the action function works, but now I do